# How to Use WebSocket.acceptWithActor with BroadCast in Playframework2.3.7

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.3

How to use WebSocket.acceptWithActor with BroadCast in Playframework2.3.7

I don't want to write Iteratee in Broadcasting.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets

I want to push all clients when receive message from client.

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (textGenerator:TextGenerator) extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(textGenerator.welcomeText))


  }
  def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
    MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
  }

  object MyWebSocketActor {
    def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
  }

  class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    private[this] var (channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]
    override def receive = {
      case msg: String =>
        out ! msg
    }
    override def postStop() = {
      Logger.info("Disconnected!")
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using `LookupEventBus` from `akka` framework instead. You can subscribe actors to specific channel and let event bus do the broadcasting job for you. Subscribing to channel named `sample`:

```
WebSocket.withActor((out) -> {
    eventBus.subscribe(out, "sample");
    return Props.create(SampleActor.class, out, eventBus);
});
```

`eventBus` - extension of `LookupEventBus`.
`SampleActor` - extension of `UntypedActor`.

The only tricky part is to unsubscribe the actor from event bus which can be done in `postStop()` method of `UntypedActor`.

Comment: No problem. I leave implementations of extensions to you, however if you have any issues, let me know.

Comment: Could you expand a bit of please.I don't know eventBus object.And I wish this scala version.

Comment: It is abstract class `LookupEventBus` from akka-actor 2.11.